# Error installing httparty

Tags: ruby, rubygems, httparty

I have followed the steps to install httparty properly, including installing the dev kit. but I still get the following error.

```
C:\Ruby193>gem install httparty
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing httparty:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

I do not have a lot of experience with Ruby

Comment: You have install make, and exist in your path?

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Ruby 1.8.9 Httparty 0.11.0 was compatible with my ruby version.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating your RubyGems to an older version `rvm install rubygems 1.8.29` and then try installing httparty again. It looks like that might work...but I am also new to Ruby so I'm kind of guessing here haha!

Comment: One of the requirements for httparty is Ruby 1.9.3 or newer.

Comment: Is this post on GitHub similar to the post we're talking about here? https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977